# Exponential Distribution - Conditional

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

Suppose that the lifetime of an electronic component has exponential distribution
with mean $100$ hours. Find the expected lifetime of the component, given that it
has already been in use for $50$ hours.

Would someone please help me with this one?

This is what I got, ${\rm E}[X \mid X > c] = {\rm E}[X] + c = \frac{1}{\lambda} + c.$ Not sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct. The exponential distribution is memoryless so we have

$$E(X \mid X \gt 50)=50+E(X)$$